# How to render data in django to AJAX?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to send a json value to ajax from django class based view and the data i am sending will be appended in html through ajax. but i am not able to send value from back end to front end successfully.

```
class DetailView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'list.html'

    def get_context_data(self,*args, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailView,self).get_context_data()
        list_view = GetList().get_data(self.request)
        movie_list = list.json()
        context['list']= movie_list
        print(movie_list)
        return context
```

So this code is sending only template value to the ajax data, when i do the console.log(data) on success call it shows me whole html code of the 'list.html' in both alert and console.log . But it prints all the values in cmd console.

```
cclass DetailView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'list.html'


    def get(self,request):
        list_view = GetList().get_data(self.request)
        movie_list = list.json()
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(movie_list))
```

this code prints all the values on respective html, but doesnt call ajax function.so no values showing in console.log.

this is my ajax call,first i am trying to just see weather i'm successfully getting the values on success call or not.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            method :'GET',
            url: '/detail',

            success: function(data){
            alert(data)
            console.log(data)
            },
        })
    })
</script>
```

So, how can i achieve my desired result? I want to get value in ajax call so i cal show those values in a table which is in a list form

Comment: Can you explain more about receive data using ajax? Is it possible to receive data by ajax?

Comment: @seuling i mean on success ajax call i want data sent by django view in ajax success function `success: function(data)`, so that i can parse the data and append in html table.

Comment: Oh I understand. You can use `JsonResponse` for this. I will leave an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JsonResponse` to send json data. (You can see detail in docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects))

like below

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

class DetailView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'list.html'

def get(self,request):
    list_view = GetList().get_data(self.request)
    movie_list = list.json()
    return JsonResponse(movie_list, status=200)
```

btw, you have to aware your data type. `JsonResponse` automatically serialize your data so you don't have to use `json()` for your data.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the response, i tried this earlier, it prints all the values on the respective url bearing template 'list.html' and class 'DetailView' and doesnt call the respective ajax call, please see the attached pic in updated question of mine.

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak Maybe that's because of `TemplateView`. You don't need template for your view that send json object to the template. It means you should split your view - `DetailView` for the real detail page / and other view like `JsonView` for receive and send the json objects

Comment: so with method should i use in class?get or get_context_data? that other view should be which method?

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak You should use `get`. anyway, `get` and `get_context_data` is completely different. Now you send ajax request using `GET` method - so your view received request using `get` method.

Comment: now able to render the html page with get method but  still not able to figure it out which method to use in both django view and ajax to render json values

Comment: did it,used put method! thanks for making me understand the method splitting philosophy..

Comment: Glad to hear that! Please upvote if the answer is helpful!